# how to make html content in browser center?

Tags: css, html

I'm new to html/css, I have tried many times on a simple html/css file, but still not working. I want to make the content in center of the browser.

two source code are under same directory, here's the source code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<hr>
<h2>Head Title2</h2>
<p align="center">write something in the center</p>

<hr>
<h4>Content</h4>
<div class="centered">
Introduction<br>
Chapter<br>
<ol>
    <li>Chapter-1<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-2<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-3<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-2<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-3<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<hr>
<h4>Reference</h4>
<ul>
    <li>book1</li>
    <li>book2</li>
    <li>book3</li>
</ul>

</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
}

h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

p {
    text-indent: 25px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* !!! */
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

but all the content are in left part. it shows like this:
[image]

I want the content in center part, and still the same format. what should I do ?

besides, I found my h1-h4 css not working, when I modify the font-size, index.html didn't change at all. why is it ?

---

thank for your help, after reading @J.Sahbu's code, I update my source code like this:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<hr>
<h2>Head Title2</h2>
<p align="center">write something in the center</p>

<hr>
<h4>Content</h4>
Introduction<br>
Chapter<br>
<ol>
    <li>Chapter-1<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-2<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-3<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-2<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-3<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<hr>
<h4>Reference</h4>
<ul>
    <li>book1</li>
    <li>book2</li>
    <li>book3</li>
</ul>

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
}

h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}


p {
    text-indent: 25px;
}

body {
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

This style is actually what I want.

Comment: add css line,  body {
    text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code. Just copy and paste below HTML And CSS as it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<hr>
<h2>Head Title2</h2>
<p align="center">write something in the center</p>

<hr>
<h4>Content</h4>
<div class="centered">
Introduction<br>
Chapter<br>
<ol>
    <li>Chapter-1<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-2<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-3<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-2<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-3<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<hr>
<h4>Reference</h4>
<ul>
    <li>book1</li>
    <li>book2</li>
    <li>book3</li>
</ul>

</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body
{
 font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;    
      text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}


p {
    text-indent: 25px;
}



.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: Just 5 min i will check it and give a proper solution

Comment: Code corrected. Please update the html and css in the answer area

Comment: You have down vote please upvote this answer and make as correct answer

Comment: @zhaochenyou There is a much better way to center than setting a fixed width. If you resize this solution you'll see how the its content will start break line, which my solution does not

Comment: @zhaochenyou We can use @ media screen to control breaking issues in small screen

Comment: @zhaochenyou and _J. Shabu_, that will be a really bad idea for doing a simple thing like this.

Comment: @J.Shabu, actually it's not me who downvote your answer, I didn't downvote anyone ... I upvote.

Comment: @LGSon, would you like to share your source code ? I'm quite new to html/css, I don't know the ```media screen```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most natural way to center content horizontal is to use `display: inline-block;` on the element and `text-align: center` on its parent.

Its advantage over `margin: 0 auto` on a block element, it doesn't need a width, it simply adjust based on its content width

So change your `centered` rule to this, and it will center properly

```
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As the `text-align: center` on the parent makes text inside the `centered` element also align centered, like with the

> Introduction
>   Chapter

you simply add `text-align: left` to the `centered` rule

```
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
}

h4 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Cambria,Calibri,"Arial","Microsoft YaHei","黑体","宋体",sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

/*  removed this as it cause the text to not center correct
p {
    text-indent: 25px;
}
*/

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* !!! */
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<h2>Head Title2</h2>
<p align="center">write something in the center</p>

<hr>
<h4>Content</h4>
<div class="centered">
Introduction<br>
Chapter<br>
<ol>
    <li>Chapter-1<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-2<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1</li>
        <li>Section-2</li>
        <li>Section-3</li>
        <li>Section-4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Chapter-3<br>
    <ol>
        <li>Section-1<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-2<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Section-3<br>
        <ol>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<hr>
<h4>Reference</h4>
<ul>
    <li>book1</li>
    <li>book2</li>
    <li>book3</li>
</ul>

</div>
<hr>
```